# Adjective meaning "making oneself feel better about oneself by doing something good after doing something bad"

Tags: single-word-requests

I tried looking it up and couldn't find the word with the meaning I needed, the reverse dictionary didn't help either.

What I found:

- "redemptory", but from what I understand it's 1. old 2. sounds odd 3. doesn't mean exactly what I'm looking for.
- "redemptive", but, again, from what I understand, it is mostly associated with Christianity + the meaning is far off, so it's not for me.
- "redeeming" means "making someone or something seem less bad", so it's also not what I need, since someone seems less bad in someone else's eyes, and I need an adjective describing a feeling coming from within.

In general, "redeem" and its forms seem to focus more on redeeming yourself in someone else's eyes rather than your own.

**Context sentence:** He didn't know why he was helping her. After all he'd done, it felt right. ________, even.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm hearing *penitent*. Anything fitting is going to be a tad formal compared to modern morality. Or *cleansing*?

Comment: @YosefBaskin wouldn't that still describe how someone else looks/what someone does rather than how someone feels? I mean, you wouldn't say "It felt right, penitent even."

Comment: Check "self-consoling" , "self-condemnation" , "self-punishing" , "self-reproach" , "self-sacrifice" + similar words. **I think "self-reproaching" is the best, with "self-consoling" coming close**

Comment: @Prem I'm actually looking for a positive adjective, as is said in the title, something that comes after doing the bad thing *and* after the guilt that comes with it, so "self-reproaching" doesn't work. Self-consoling doesn't have the meaning that I need, but it's a good suggestion in this particular context

Comment: Hmmmm, "Palliative" & "therapeutic" may work.

Comment: Some More Choices : "Curative" & "mitigative"

Comment: Did you try a thesaurus?  Look up "atone" for example and see if anything fits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might use the gerundial adjective **atoning**.

> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/atone?q=atoning)
> *Atone*:
> to do something that shows you are sorry for something bad that you did or for something that you failed to do

“… it felt right, atoning, even”.

The corresponding noun is **atonement**. “He felt a sense of atonement”, or “He felt atonement”. “He felt right, an atonement, even.”

Comment: that's it! thank you so much. can't believe i didn't find this one earlier.

Comment: You are welcome. I sympathise. It is not always easy to know where you are going until you arrive :)